# Battery Pack for Electric motor

Tags: batteries

I’m seeking to find/design a battery that can power a 230 kW electric motor at 680V for atleast 10 seconds. I don’t know much about battery mechanics besides simple circuit equations, so I’m seeking general advice on how to go about finding/designing a battery for my use case, and how to calculate figures such as weight, cell configuration, best battery composition etc.

This is the motor I’m looking to run: http://emrax.com/products/emrax-268/

Thanks!

Comment: So you are building a electric dragster?  I like the idea but currently 10C is pretty high and 30C is about the envelope, so you aren't likely to dump the energy safely in less than a few minutes. If you really want to optimize power to weight ratio for 10 second use case you can try super capacitors.

Comment: It is effectively an electric dragster. What are you referring to with 10C and 30C?

Comment: C number is the charging or discharging current measured relative to fully charge/discharge in an hour. For typical 18650 battery the capacity is usually between 2200mAh to 2800mAh, so 1C means 2200mA-2800mA. 10C is 10 times that, meaning your battery would charge/discharge in 6 minutes. A battery rated for 30C discharge isn't very easy to find. But just like motors, for 10 seconds you might be able to safely overdrive it significantly, at your own risk.

Answer (score 3):

There is an upper limit to how fast a power source can deliver its charge, that is, how much power it can deliver. Generally, the larger the battery, the more power it can deliver. For a dragster, you will want to use the lowest mass battery you can. If the battery is over-sized to get the power, then you are hauling excess mass around which will hurt your performance.

Batteries, especially batteries optimised for high power for short durations, have a maximum current rated in C. For example, a battery rated 5Ah with a max discharge of 20C would be able to deliver 100A. In naive theory, you might expect it to be able to do this for a nominal 60/20 = 3 minutes, but fast discharge reduces capacity, so you would reasonably be able to expect only up to 2 minutes or so.

With your 10 second event discharge, you would probably want to design for a 30 second nominal discharge, to allow for capacity loss and a tolerance to avoid deep discharge, which is a current rating of 120C.

I have started to see LiPo race packs become available that actually claim 65 to 130C. So it looks like you're there. Buy one of these, test it to destruction, see what voltage and life you get from it at 120C, and see whether its claims are realistic. You would expect a short life using (abusing?) a battery like this, which will get expensive on replacements, but hey, electric dragster doesn't sound like a cheap hobby to start with.

If you use a lower power rated battery, and there are lots available in the 20C to 40C range, then you will have to install a higher mass of batteries in the car. However, the discharge in 10 seconds won't be as deep, so they'll last much longer. Do you want a heavy car that's cheap to run, or a lighter faster battery guzzler? The energy capacity is not the problem, you're fighting the power rate.

The alternative to LiPos is supercapacitors. These *will* be able to dump all their energy in 10 seconds, without a significant capacity loss or lifetime degradation for the fast discharge. But, they start with a much lower energy density than LiPos, so you will need a large mass of them. The power rate is not the problem, you're fighting energy capacity.

Do some research into high rate LiPos and high capacity supercaps. Fire up a spread sheet and work out the cost, both in $_total, $_per_run, and kg, of the minimum energy and power capacity that will run your motor. The problem is that these three different costs scale differently with the different technologies, and with your feelings about performance, so only **you** can apply the relative importance to them to make a final decision.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the info so far! So I did some extra research, and Found a battery rated for 150C at this link. https://www.maxamps.com/lipo-4000-12s-44-4v-battery-pack
Not saying I will go with this particular choice without comparing others, but say I was to pick this. Are these calculations valid?
Motor draws 400 amps for 30 seconds so I need a battery that is atleast 3333 mAh. 3.33Ah * 150C means it can support around 500 amps of discharge. The battery however, is at 44.4 Volts, which means I would need 680V/44.4 Volts ~ 16 Batteries? (motor is 680V)Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @teku45 pretty much, yes. I'd do the sums as 230kW/680v = 340A, so at 150C, need only 340/150 = 2.3Ah. Anything above 2.3Ah is costing you weight UNLESS that 150C capability comes at a large weight premium, check lower C batteries to see if they're lighter. The 44.4v for a 12S pack is at their NOMINAL 3.7 voltage, the peak of 4.2 per cell means a 50.4v pack at the start, maybe 40v at the end. All this will be going through your SMPS controller, so you can trade volts for amps at constant power. As the race goes on, the voltage will drop. You will want 680v at the end, so perhaps use more ...

Comment: @teku45 ... than 16 batteries of less than 2Ah, unless your controller can also boost (most are buck only) in which case you could use fewer of a high Ah.

Comment: This sounds like a fun project. Make sure you work that motor hard. Are you building your own controller? See [this Q/A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336069/brushed-motor-vs-bldc) for what stops you overloading a motor. At zero speed, you have no power, so could drive a very large current into the motor, limited by demagnetisation or wheel slip, which comes first.

Comment: No the motor we found has a list of suggested controllers. So that's what I'm not entirely sure about. I listed the motor above, but I'm having trouble figuring out what its behavior would be over the course of 10-12 seconds. How do we work the motor as hard as possible? I don't understand, from the listed max Power, Voltage, and amperage stats how far we can push it, and what our system constraints are. We are effectively developing a ~100kg sled.

Comment: The specs don't have enough info. They have a 2 minute current, but you want a 10 second current. You need to ask for the demagnetisation current, and the mass of the copper windings, because a 10s run is likely to be adiabatic, that is, no heat lost during the run, so it all has to be absorbed in the mass of the copper. Pre-cooling the windings before a run, with CO2 or even LN2, is doubly beneficial, lower resistance, and higher heat capacity. You want wheel-slip to be the torque limiting factor, not motor, controller or battery limitations.